# Mandrill api log says message is sent, but I don't receive it, and it doesn't show in activity

Tags: mandrill

Using a production key on Mandrill I am attempting to send an email. Previously this has worked without issue. However now, despite receiving a successful response from the API, visible in the api log, no email is being sent, and nothing is present in the outbound activity log.

If I check the api log for the message which appeared to fail it displays:

```
[
    {
        "email": [email_address],
        "status": "sent",
        "_id": [id],
        "reject_reason": null
    }
]
```

Replacing the id in the content view of a sent email, with the id from a failed one displays a correctly formatted email:

e.g. https://mandrillapp.com/activity/content?id=20151214_[put_the_id_here]

Is this a bug? What is causing it? Where can I see more information about what happened? How can I monitor if this happens again in the future? How can I prevent it from happening in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been in contact with Mandrill support regarding the issue, which they described as 'very strange indeed'. Deleting the API key and generating a new one fixed the issue, but there is no explanation as to why this is they case, how to detect the problem, or how to stop it from happening again in the future.

The messages in question were never actually sent by Mandrill, and displayed no SMTP events, despite reporting as sent by their API

Answer (score 1):

Something else to check is to make sure you're using a working API key instead of a [test one](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582447-Does-Mandrill-Have-a-Test-Mode-or-Sandbox-).  As the name suggests, test keys are designed to work just like a regular key, so the feedback to your program will be identical, but the messages won't actually be sent.

You can see if this is the problem by going to the [Mandrill settings](https://mandrillapp.com/settings) and looking at the list of API keys.  Test keys have a very clear `This is a test key` message listed.

This probably won't be an issue if you generated the key yourself, but if you inherited this project it's worth taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue like this last week. The "sent" status only indicates that Mandrill sent it. But reception of the email message is confirmed only if there is a SMTP event corresponding to it with code starting with 2, (example 250 etc), in the info api response, like the following:

```
 "smtp_events": [
            {
                "ts": 1442448422,
                "type": "sent",
                "diag": "250 SmtpThread-4622542-14682902148@ps-they-19.uk.miplecast.lan Received OK",
                "source_ip": "505.207.171.171",
                "destination_ip": "705.139.255.221",
                "size": 29501
            }
```

check this link for more info.
https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582697-How-to-Confirm-If-an-Email-Was-Actually-Delivered

the issue could be on the recipient server as well, due which delivery could be delayed. In our experience last week, the message was delivered 4 hours after being Sent. we were not able to establish the reason yet why, this delay happened.

HTH,